# IntelliJ plugin development getting actual object from PsiAnnotationMemberValue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Alright, so in the plugin that I'm working on, I need to get the value of parameters passed to an annotation. I was given a solution on the #idea-users freenode channel, being that I should cast the PsiAnnotationMemberValue to a PsiLiteral, and call getValue(). and While that worked for primitives, and for things like Strings, now I'm trying to get a custom enum value. And when I tried to do that, my code threw a ClassCastException with the following error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.java.PsiReferenceExpressionImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.PsiLiteral
```

Code:

```
@Override
public boolean eventIgnoresCancelled(PsiMethod method) {

    PsiLiteral literal = null;

    for (PsiAnnotation annotation : method.getModifierList().getAnnotations()) {
        if(annotation.getQualifiedName().contains("IsCancelled")) {
            literal = ((PsiLiteral) annotation.findAttributeValue("value"));
        }
    }

    if(literal == null || literal.getValue() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Object tristateValue = literal.getValue();
    try {
        String name = (String) tristateValue.getClass().getMethod("name").invoke(tristateValue);
        return name.equalsIgnoreCase("TRUE") || name.equalsIgnoreCase("UNDEFINED");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code shouldn't assume that all annotation values are literals, they can also be .class expressions, arrays, other annotations etc. And references. IDEA's PSI doesn't know anything about your enums, but given a PsiReferenceExpression annotation value, you can check its name (getReferenceName()) or even do resolve() and get to the actual enum constant that also has getName() method. And, as can be seen from the exception, you already have PsiReferenceExpression object, so please just handle this case in addition to PsiLiteral.